# No consigo centrar el encabezado

Tags: css, float, display

He querido aplicar un borde inferior (a modo de subrayado) para un encabezado. Para que el "subrayado" ocupara solo el ancho del texto se me ha ocurrido convertir la etiquita en `inline` (no se si hay otra manera desde CSS).

El problema es que intento centrar este encabezado con margin:0 auto y no se centra. ¿Por qué?

Además no entiendo por qué, al aplicar un float al párrafo, este se sube hasta la altura del encabezado, ya que pensaba que el float se genera desde la etiqueta en la que se aplica hacia abajo (he indicado el borde rojo para que se vea mas claro su borde superior).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> <!--Se elige "en" para construir la pagina en ingles-->
<head>
        
<title>Uso de la propiedad display</title>

<style>
html{background-color:blue;}

body{width:60%;
background-color:gray;

margin:0 auto;
padding:30px;}

h1{border-bottom:3px dashed black;
                
display:inline;
                
margin:0px auto
font-size:2rem;}

p{ font-size:2rem;
width:50%;
float:right;
border:1px solid red;}

img{border:10px solid black;
margin-top:20px;}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Rio: Curso de agua</h1>

<p>Un río o flujo de agua es una corriente natural de agua que fluye con continuidad por un cauce en la superficie terrestre. Posee un caudal determinado, rara vez es constante a lo largo del año, y desemboca en el mar, en un lago o en otro río, en cuyo caso se denomina afluente.</p>
    
<img src="rioAmazonas.jpg" title="Rio Amazonas" width="40%">
        
</body>
</html>
```

Un saludo

Comment: No se centra precisamente porq la convertiste en inline. Su width sera su contenido. Podrias usar flexbox para centrarla

Comment: Podria subrayar unicamente el texto del encabezado sin convertirla en inline??

Comment: Realmente no estas subrayando el texto en un contenedor block sino el contenedor en si mismo. Para el texto usa textdecoration: underline

Comment: Gracias Hernán. El problema es que según tengo entendido con text-decoration no puedes modificar ni estilo de trazo, ni color, ni grosor ni padding

Comment: Claro. Por eso t recomiendo uses flexbox. Pones el elemento q qieres centrar en un div con una clase y a esa clase le das estilo display: flex justifyContent:center y lo tendras centrado al elemento inline

Comment: Gracias Hernán. También he comprobado que sin necesidad de aplicar flexbox funciona si al div le aplicamos la propiedad text-align:center.

Comment: Si. Esa es otra podibilidad

Answer (score 0):

Tal y como dijo el usuario **Hernán Garcia**, la solución simple es poniendo el encabezado en un **Div**, al cual le aplicas el "***Justify-content: Center;***" en una **clase**. Lo que hará que el texto dentro del **Div** se **centre** de manera Horizontal.

Espero haberte ayudado, buen día.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en"> <!--Se elige "en" para construir la pagina en ingles-->
    <head>
            
    <title>Uso de la propiedad display</title>

    <style>
    html{background-color:blue;}

    body{width:60%;
    background-color:gray;

    margin:0 auto;
    padding:30px;}

    h1{border-bottom:3px dashed black;
                    
    display:inline;
                    
    margin:0px auto
    font-size:2rem;}

/* La clase aplica el centrado a los elementos dentro del Div */
    .centrar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    }

    p{ font-size:2rem;
    width:50%;
    float:right;
    border:1px solid red;}

    img{border:10px solid black;
    margin-top:20px;}
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
<div class="centrar">
    <h1>Rio: Curso de agua</h1>
</div>
    <p>Un río o flujo de agua es una corriente natural de agua que fluye con continuidad por un cauce en la superficie terrestre. Posee un caudal determinado, rara vez es constante a lo largo del año, y desemboca en el mar, en un lago o en otro río, en cuyo caso se denomina afluente.</p>
        
    <img src="rioAmazonas.jpg" title="Rio Amazonas" width="40%">
            
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Un placer (Y) ;)